# Was Mr. Beast invited to ride the Titan submarine?

Tags: celebrities

[Mr Beast Tweeted on Jun 25, 2023](https://twitter.com/MrBeast/status/1672952297163218946?s=20) that "[he] was invited earlier this month to ride the titanic submarine, I said no. Kind of scary that I could have been on it." However, the screenshot, presumably from iMessage is blue. A blue message means that the person who screenshotted the message is the same as the sender. If MrBeast is posting his screenshot, the invitation message would presumably be either gray or green (as he shouldn't have been the sender).

[image]

Comment: Could you please give some context about the blue iMessage comment? Why do you think this is from iMessage and why wouldnt it be blue if it were?

Comment: added context. the blue is more weird because in iMessage is is supposed to denote it is *your* message, which seems weird since the screenshot looks like it was taken by Jimmy.

Comment: Not an iPhone user, but my cursory research says blue means messages transmitted via the iMessage system over the internet and green is an SMS message over the phone network.

Comment: It's really sad that these types of questions are allowed just because people having seen a tweet makes it _NOTABLE_. How come the _content_ is not a factor in notability? This question has absolutely zero relevance for anything.

Comment: @pipe, I can understand your frustration that this is not _relevant_ to any broader or deeper context. However, I think because of the sheer notability of the Titan implosion, it is helpful to be able to correct misinformation in this situation rather than not care.

Comment: How is this notable? Anyone can claim anything on Twitter?

Comment: @gerrit I have seen the idea that it was "faked" being reposted all over social media (Instagram / twitter / etc) in response to the virality of both Jimmy and the incident. Perhaps notable isn't the right word because I think notable more implies it is _worthy_ of attention. Regardless, it has attention.

Comment: @pipe/gerrit: We want to tackle *widely-believed* claims. That's hard to prove, so we accept *widely-read* as a proxy. Here, notability isn't about *importance*; it is about being seen and/or repeated, even though some of the claims may be fluff. With >74M views, this tweet counts.

Comment: [Here's an article on Sky News about it](https://news.sky.com/story/youtube-star-mrbeast-says-he-turned-down-trip-on-doomed-titanic-submersible-12909364). Surely that's notable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

He clarified that the screenshot of the invitation was sent to him by the person who offered it.

https://twitter.com/MrBeast/status/1673102128150200321?s=20

While the Twitter replies call this dubious, it seems even more dubious that he would post a fake text not remembering how colors work.

It's also not clear if he was being invited to join the doomed dive, or a later dive scheduled for "the end of this month" (June). Context implies the latter, as the roster for [each dive](https://news.sky.com/story/titanic-sub-implosion-billionaire-was-offered-cut-price-tickets-for-doomed-voyage-but-pulled-out-over-schedule-clash-12908345) seems to have been decided about a month in advance.

Two other YouTubers, Jake Koehler and Alan X El Mundo, were also invited at various points: Jake [rode on the sub in early June](https://youtu.be/O-8U08yJlb8) and Alan had gone [the previous year](https://youtu.be/RAncVNaw5N0). So invitations may have been widely distributed to travel YouTubers.

Comment: I'd also note that Mr. Beast is the biggest Youtuber in the US, he'd definitely be #1 on anyone's list for an event like that.